# How to set GHCi prompt to display modules separated by a custom separator?

Tags: haskell, prompt, ghci

Currently this is how my ghci prompt looks like:

[image]

And I want to make it look like this:

[image]

or like this

[image]

Any ideas on how I can do this? My configuration(ghci.conf) file's contents is as shown below

```
:set prompt "\ESC[33m\STX[%s]\ESC[38;5;86m\STX \x03BB > \ESC[0m\STX"
```

in which I followed the syntax written on:

https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.1-alpha1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:set%20prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prompt-function`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.1-alpha1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:set%20prompt-function) instead of `prompt` to run more advanced Haskell functions for the prompt. Here's an example `ghci.conf` for your second prompt:

```hs
:{
prompter :: [String] -> Int -> IO String
prompter modules line = return $
    concat [ "\ESC[33m\STX["
           , Data.List.intercalate ", " modules
           , "]\ESC[38;5;86m\STX \x03BB > \ESC[0m\STX"
           ]
:}

:set prompt-function prompter
```

Or, for numbers, you can utilize [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith):

```hs
:{
prompter :: [String] -> Int -> IO String
prompter modules line = return $
    concat [ "\ESC[33m\STX["
           -- this is the only line that changed
           , Data.List.intercalate ", " $ zipWith (\n m -> concat [show n, ".", m]) [1..] modules
           , "]\ESC[38;5;86m\STX \x03BB > \ESC[0m\STX"
           ]
:}

:set prompt-function prompter
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to write the continuation line, but it's very similar and just involves [`prompt-cont-function`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.1-alpha1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:set%20prompt-cont-function).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a question tho, I used the code you've provided me above and made it as follows: [link](https://urlzs.com/F9JEu) and the result is something like this: [link](https://urlzs.com/TXhGA), however, whenever I press ctrl-l(clear screen) it becomes like this: [link](https://urlzs.com/q7yRT). Do you have any idea why this happens and how I could make it look like: [link](https://urlzs.com/TXhGA) whenever I clear the terminal screen? @Aplet123